# Why do parent_id and post_id have different values in facebook webhook

Tags: facebook, webhooks

When I received an update through webhooks, which came from updating the cover photo and commenting on the post created from it, the post_id was different from parent_id. However, when executed in the graph api, they both refer to the post noted by post_id.

I'm curious to know why since from what I've noticed they (i.e. post_id and parent_id) are usually equal if the update is a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the response of Facebook team, the reason why I experienced this was because post_id was referencing the uploaded photo whereas parent_id was referencing the story connected to the post.

The reason why every comment I made in that post also had different parent_ids was due to post having a has many relationship with stories. Each comment changes' parent_id returned by webhooks was referencing a different story associated with the post hence why the parent_ids were different from each other despite being under the same post.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. I have come across a similar situation: user posts a photo through our app via the FB API. Then we also get the webhook saying a photo was added, but the ID's were different. The Facebook API's used to be the best social network API's to work with. Now they are just a mess. THANKS FOR JOY AND PAIN (WASTED TIME), FACEBLARB!